# Can I Active Two Merchant Accounts With Diffrent Email Address Integration For Paypal

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal

I would like to active two **payapl** account in 1 Store like That 
1:Payments Pro
2:Payments Standard
Magento Version 1.9.2.4

Comment: Just curious what you are trying to achieve with using 2 accounts? Merely using Payments Pro you still have all the checkout options of Payments Standard inside your magento store such as express checkout and pay with paypal.

Comment: thanks @ Eirik I want to do like that if user order with credit card it use different  merchant account and use paypal redirected to the PayPal website.To use different  merchant account I want to active both account on Same Time.

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant solution would be using different store views. Visually they can be identical but you can set different PayPal configurations for each.

You can initially switch user to the desired store view based on the geo location information of whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks for reply I have just one Store  So i would like to active two merchant account on same time .

Comment: Okay. In one store it is not possible.